# Should I be worried about files in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Deleted\` that Priviliaged Powershell can't delete?

Tags: windows

Going through my event viewer I stumbled upon two folders in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Deleted\`

1. Clipchamp.Clipchamp_2.9.1.0_neutral__yxz26nhyzhsrtf4b62535-506c-4978-ab73-b65ae9af9b03
2. SpotifyAB.SpotifyMusic_1.232.997.0_x64__zpdnekdrzrea08f17d678-b99e-4af7-9178-d6dd2f37975e

The event that triggered this find was `error 0x12C: Deleting file \\?\C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Deleted\Clipchamp.Clipchamp_2.9.1.0_neutral__yxz26nhyzhsrtf4b62535-506c-4978-ab73-b65ae9af9b03\Clipchamp\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll failed.`

After some research I decided that it would be best if I just delete them. I opened an escalated powershell instance and tried, but got refused.

```
Remove-Item : Cannot remove item C:\Program
Files\WindowsApps\Deleted\Clipchamp.Clipchamp_2.9.1.0_neutral__yxz26nhyzhsrtf4b62535-506c-4978-ab73-b65ae9af9b03\Clipchamp.cli\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll: Access to
the path 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll' is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-Item Clipchamp.cli
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemUnAuthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
Remove-Item : Cannot remove item C:\Program
Files\WindowsApps\Deleted\Clipchamp.Clipchamp_2.9.1.0_neutral__yxz26nhyzhsrtf4b62535-506c-4978-ab73-b65ae9af9b03\Clipchamp.cli\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions.dll:
Access to the path 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions.dll' is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-Item Clipchamp.cli
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions.dll:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemUnAuthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
Remove-Item : Cannot remove item C:\Program
Files\WindowsApps\Deleted\Clipchamp.Clipchamp_2.9.1.0_neutral__yxz26nhyzhsrtf4b62535-506c-4978-ab73-b65ae9af9b03\Clipchamp.cli\System.Buffers.dll: Access to the path
'System.Buffers.dll' is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-Item Clipchamp.cli
```

Should I be worried if not why am I having trouble deleting this folder?

Comment: One thing’s for sure: You should not mess with the folder’s permissions. This could make you unable to run any “apps”.

Comment: By default no user account should have write access to WindowsApps so a directory within WindowsApps would also be restricted.

Answer (score -1):

It shouldn’t really be concerning unless there any signs of malicious behaviour(those dlls mentioned in the error should be benign unless you have downloaded some malicious dlls that are impersonating as benign ones)Please refer to the following https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/what-is-program-fileswindowsappsdeleted-for-can-i/e050e07c-09a4-4c08-877e-3003b1bd6f85
And as for the access denied error , it could be due to multiple reasons , one of them being that the file is already being accessed by some other program .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).